# Can't ever remove partition?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, core-storage

Running Mountain Lion.

I added a partition with Disk Utility and then had second thoughts about it. I'd like to remove the partition i created, MacSSD2 and hand over its space back to MacSSD. As you can see, the "-" button is disabled even when i select the MacSSD2 partition.

[image]

This is the output from command line:

```
    ~ - Tue Aug 14 10:12:00: diskutil list
    /dev/disk0
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *512.1 GB   disk0
       1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
       2:                  Apple_HFS MacSSD                  425.7 GB   disk0s2
       3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             784.2 MB   disk0s5
       4:          Apple_CoreStorage MacSSD 2                85.3 GB    disk0s4   <--- Want to remove this
       5:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s6
    /dev/disk1
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:                  Apple_HFS MacSSD2                *84.9 GB    disk1

~ - Tue Aug 14 10:18:33: sudo gpt -r show disk1
      start       size  index  contents
          0  165900968
```

Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried removing it using the Disk Utility offered by OSX's install environment you can reach by booting from the rescue partition, or installation media? If that doesn't work, please edit your question to include the output of the terminal commands `diskutil list` (and point out which partition you want to delete) and `sudo gpt -r show disk0` (or whichever disk number contains the partition - you can see this in the previous command's output; the latter command requires your password and shows the raw partition table).

Answer (score 20):

Looks like your MacSSD2 partition has been turned into a Core Storage volume. Core Storage is Apple's underlying system for disk encryption - I assume you enabled encryption when you created the partition?

You can show the Core Storage volume group using the command `diskutil cs list` and then delete it using `diskutil cs delete <volumegroup-uuid>`, where you get the volume group's UUID from the output of the previous command.

That should either delete it entirely or make it deletable in Disk Utility.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.

Comment: @pmdj I have the same problem since i split my Drive to two for installation of Yosemite in the other but later realized that I allocated too less for Yosemite and there is no way I can re-size the logical volume. Can you tell me how I partition this without making the second partition as CS Volume? OR can I use `resizeVolume` safely?